# Querying data from different rows using ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, analytics, oracle12c

I have this table:

```
+------+-------+---------+----------------------------+
| id   | date  | value   |  value2 | value3           |
+------+-------+---------+----------------------------+
| 1    | 5/28  | 100     | NULL    | NULL             |
| 1    | 5/27  | 200     | NULL    | NULL             |
| 1    | 5/26  | 300     | 10      | NULL             |
| 1    | 5/25  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             |
| 1    | 5/24  | ...     | 20      | NULL             |
| 1    | 5/23  | ...     | ....    | 50               |
| 1    | 5/22  | ...     | ....    | 30               |
| 1    | 5/21  | ...     | ....    | NULL             |
| 1    | 5/20  | ...     | ....    | ...              |
| 1    | 5/19  | ...     | ....    | ...              |
| 1    | 5/18  | ...     | ....    | ...              |
| 1    | 5/17  | ...     | ....    | ...              |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

I need to query the latest possible values per column. So if value2 is NULL on a day that value3 is not, it'll be getting the previous record which value2 isn't null. I'm not sure if this make any sense but here's the resulting table I wanted to have:

```
+------+-------+-------+--------+----------+
| id   | date  | value | value2 |  value3  |
+------+-------+-------+--------+----------+
| 1    | 5/28  | 100   | 10     | 50       |
+------+-------+---------------------------+
```

The date will always be the latest (in this example, it's 5/28) then as for the rest, I need to get the latest value for each column even if it doesn't match the date.

Will this be even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last_value window function can also be used for this.

**Example:**

> ```
> create table test_table(id int, "date" date, value int, value2 int, value3 int);
> ```

> ```
> insert into test_table (id, "date", value, value2, value3)
> select 1, date '2018-05-28', 100, null, null from dual union
> select 1, date '2018-05-27', 200, null, null from dual union
> select 1, date '2018-05-26', 300, 10, null   from dual union
> select 1, date '2018-05-23', 500, null, 50   from dual;
> ```

> ```
> insert into test_table (id, "date", value, value2, value3)
> select 2, "date" + 1, value+100, value2+10, value3+10 from test_table;
> ```

> ```
> select
>  id,
>  max("date") as "date",
>  max(lastValue1) as value,
>  max(lastValue2) as value2,
>  max(lastValue3) as value3
> from
> (
>    select id, "date",
>     last_value(value ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by "date" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as lastValue1,
>     last_value(value2 ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by "date" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as lastValue2,
>     last_value(value3 ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by "date" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as lastValue3
>    from test_table
> ) q
> group by id;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | date      | VALUE | VALUE2 | VALUE3
> -- | --------- | ----- | ------ | ------
>  1 | 28-MAY-18 |   100 |     10 |     50
>  2 | 29-MAY-18 |   200 |     20 |     60
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=06b4938b2a783a8566d7f3f9d183707f)*

Answer (score 4):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (datum, value1, value2, value3) as
  2    (select date '2018-05-28', 100, null, null from dual union
  3     select date '2018-05-27', 200, null, null from dual union
  4     select date '2018-05-26', 300, 10, null   from dual union
  5     select date '2018-05-23', 500, null, 50   from dual
  6    ),
  7  inter as
  8    (select
  9      first_value(datum  ignore nulls) over (order by datum desc) datum,
 10      first_value(value1 ignore nulls) over (order by datum desc) value1,
 11      first_value(value2 ignore nulls) over (order by datum desc) value2,
 12      first_value(value3 ignore nulls) over (order by datum desc) value3
 13    from test
 14    order by 1 desc nulls last, 2 desc nulls last, 3 desc nulls last, 4 desc nulls last
 15   )
 16  select *
 17  from inter
 18  where rownum = 1;

DATUM          VALUE1     VALUE2     VALUE3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
28.05.2018        100         10         50

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, just a follow up question. If i would apply this to a larger table with more dates and more variance in NULLs for the columns, I'll have to manually check each dates and create the data set for 'test'? Does this mean that whenever there's new values per column on a new date that will be commited in the table, I'll have to edit my query?

Comment: Nope. CTE (common table expression) or the WITH factoring clause I used is here just to quickly provide sample data set; otherwise, I'd have to actually CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO those rows. In your case, you'd use lines from 7 onwards, substituting "test" with the actual table name. You wouldn't have to do anything "manually". Give it a try.